# Should I check in my changes before I do rebase in clear tool

Tags: version-control, clearcase, rebase, cleartool

I use ClearCase for version control and have been working on few files in my child stream view.

Now I want to rebase to a baseline which has all the updates from other developers.

So, before I do the rebase, should I check in all my changes even though nobody has modified the files that I am working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferable to do so, in order to avoid any mishap during the rebase.

But, another approach would be, assuming you are working in a snapshot (UCM) view, to:

- use a separate dynamic view (with the same config spec) to perform the rebase
- update the snapshot view (that should not touch the currently checked out files, especially if the rebase involves different files)

Comment: Keeping a backup of the modified content remains a sensible policy.

Comment: If I do not check in the files will clear case give any warnings before it replaces my modified files?

Comment: It should, but I have been burn before, hence the precautionary step of a backup, to be on the safe side.

Comment: updating the snapshot view will only pick up files that were merged by the rebase. A rebase will update the STREAM's configspec, but not the view's. you will need to do a cleartool setcs -stream to pick up changes. Also, the rebase will fail if your checked out files need to be merged in the rebase.

Answer (score 2):

Checking in the files will preserve their contents. it is possible that your rebase will need to change the files you have checked out. Checking in your work before rebasing is a best practice and preserves your changes AS ones tied to a non-rebase activity. it may also be required depending on project and stream policies.

Having multiple development views associated with a given stream is often necessary, but keep in mind that rebasing the stream in one view does not update the other views' configurations. So, you will need to remember to manually resync those other views with the stream. Failure to do so can lead to confusion as you will see the rebase changes in one location but not the other.